# How do I create a listener within my org to let others POST to it and save data?

Tags: rest-api, wsdl2apex

What should I look into to create a service within my org to let others POST to my org and save data? For example, I have a list within my org and want to POST to it from outside salesforce (let's say a string) and each time it adds the string to the list. How would I set up the OAuth for this?

I tried creating a class, but the class isn't actually running like a webservice so there's no way that would work.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, your requirement is to explore certain business function as a web service (preferably REST),for that i'll recommend you to Salesforce developer forum wherein you can find lots of resources to develop apex web services:-

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Web_Services

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Creating_REST_APIs_using_Apex_REST

For starters, you can use a session ID instead of an OAuth 2.0 access token if you aren't handling someone else's password (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/quickstart_oauth.htm)

Obtain a session ID, for example, a SOAP API login() call returns the session ID.

Use the session ID when you send a request to the resource. Substitute the Session ID for the token value

Authorization: Bearer <SESSION ID>